# Solve for a specific variable in terms of another specified variable

Tags: simpy

I am trying to learn sympy by going through some textbook problems.
I have one that is asking to get a formula for Rankine in terms of Kelvin.

This is easy to solve without simpy (given the formulas):

(=−459.4, =5/9−1609, =+273)

With some algebra, =5r/9

But I do not know how to get solve explicitly for k in terms of r with simpy. I can have it solve the system of eqns but not sure how to specify for which variable in terms of which.

My attempt:

```
import sympy as sp
r, c, k, f = symbols('r c k f')
eq1 = sp.Eq(f, r-459.4)             # f=r-459.4
eq2 = sp.Eq(c, (5/9)*f-(160/9))         # c = (5/9)*f-(160/9)
eq3 = sp.Eq(k, c+273)             # k = c+273
ans = sp.solve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (r, c, k, f))  #3 eqns, 4 unknowns (f, r, c, k)
ans
```

yielded

{:0.555555555555556−17.7777777777778, :0.555555555555556+255.222222222222, :+459.4}

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it out using linsolve instead

```
import sympy as sp
eq1 = sp.Eq(f, r-459.4)             # f=r-459.4
eq2 = sp.Eq(c, (5/9)*f-(160/9))         # c = (5/9)*f-(160/9)
eq3 = sp.Eq(k, c+273)             # k = c+273
sp.linsolve([eq2, eq3], [k,c])  #{(0.555555555555556+255.222222222222, 0.555555555555556−17.7777777777778)}  
sp.linsolve([eq1, eq2], [c,f])   #{(0.555555555555556−273.0, −459.4)}
sp.linsolve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [k,c,f])   #{(0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556−273.0, −459.4)}
```